# SQL Union not including duplicates based on single column?

Tags: sql, oracle10g, union

I'm trying to union two tables but I need to essentially 'prefer' the first table using just one 'id' column. 
If an 'id' appears in the second table that already exists in the first, I do not want to include that record.

Query looks like this

```
            select id, col2, col3
            from table(p_package.getData(param))

            union

            select id, col2, col3 
            from table1         
            where col7 = 'pass'
            and col8 <> 'A' 
            and col9 = to_date(Date, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

the p_package.getData(param) is a pipelined function which returns a table. I would like to avoid calling this twice for performance reasons

Comment: I don't see any columns here named `id` or anything like it.  Can you explain what the `id` requirement is?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry, `id` should have been col1. Updated the question

Comment: Consider: use a common table expression for the pipelined function and then reference the CTE as an exclusion in the 2nd.  since the CTE would be in memory already; the function call shoudln't occur twice.

Comment: @xQbert thanks for that suggestion! it's exactly what I was looking for but hadn't ever heard for CTE's nor did I come across it in any of my searching

Comment: I"m assuming you double checked to ensure the execution plan didn't show the pipelined function getting hit twice.   I don't think it would occur twice since the CTE is already in memory; but I'm not POSITIVE about it ;P

Comment: @xQbert actually yeah it seems it still calls the pipelined function twice. The CTE just stores the query in memory not the data returned. Still good to know. I think I will look in to using a temp table for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function to remove the duplicates:

```sql
SELECT id, col2, col3
FROM   (
  SELECT id, col2, col3,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY priority ) AS rn
  FROM   (
    select id, col2, col3, 1 AS priority
    from   table(p_package.getData(param))
  UNION ALL
    select id, col2, col3, 2
    from table1         
    where col7 = 'pass'
    and   col8 <> 'A' 
    and   col9 = to_date(Date, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
  )
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

*and as a bonus, since you're filtering the duplicates elsewhere, you could change `UNION` to `UNION ALL`.*

If you can have duplicates `id` values from the pipelined function and you want those but not any from `table1` then:

```sql
SELECT id, col2, col3
FROM   (
  SELECT id, col2, col3, priority
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY priority ) AS rn
  FROM   (
    select id, col2, col3, 1 AS priority
    from   table(p_package.getData(param))
  UNION ALL
    select id, col2, col3, 2
    from table1         
    where col7 = 'pass'
    and   col8 <> 'A' 
    and   col9 = to_date(Date, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
  )
)
WHERE priority = 1
OR    rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to include any `col1` value in the second half of the union which would introduce a value already included in the first half, you could use an exists clause:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from table(p_package.getData(param))
union
select col1, col2, col3 
from table1 t1
where col7 = 'pass' and col8 <> 'A'and col9 = to_date(Date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') and
      not exists (select 1 from table(p_package.getData(param)) t2
                  where t1.col1 = t2.col1);
```

Comment: wouldn't this end up calling the p_package.getData() function twice?

Comment: Well I don't see any way around this TBH.  I mean, you could just do the union and sort things out afterwards, but that would also be a bunch of work.

Comment: Would using a join possibly be a way around it? I'm open to that but can't think of how

Comment: How would a join be a way around this?  The second half of the union has to "know" what the first half is doing, to avoid brining in the same `col1` value, right?

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions work but I opted to use a common table expression as suggested by xQbert

```
        with cte as
        (select id, col2, col3
        from table(p_package.getData(param)))

        select * from cte

        union

        select id, col2, col3 
        from table1         
        where col7 = 'pass'
        and col8 <> 'A' 
        and col9 = to_date(Date, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
        and id not in (select id from cte)
```

EDIT: I realized that a CTE does not actually store the data returned by a query but stores the query itself instead. While this works it does not avoid calling the pipelined function twice